# Attaching certificate to ALB with CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-route53, aws-fargate

I have a stack definition for AWS Fargate. Among other things, my stack has a load balancer, and a public IP/DNS for outside access. I made the certificate manually, using Route53 and currently attach it as:

```
Parameters:
  VPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC::Id
  SubnetA:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id
  SubnetB:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id
  Certificate:
    Type: String
    # Update with the certificate ARN from Certificate Manager, which must exist in the same region.
    # In our case, it is staging-api.mydomain.com
    Default: 'arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:505xxxxx303:certificate/03df1a1e-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-34388b5a1f67'
```

I would much rather create/update the SSL certificate upon stack creation, instead of having to depend on an external process returning an existing certificate id. In fact, I would rather do away with both my hardcoded AWS account id and the hardcoded certificate id.

Can I get/inherit the account id from the AWS principal somehow and automate the certificate management?

Answer (score 1):

In general you would use [AWS::AccountId](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html#cfn-pseudo-param-accountid) variable. But this does not work in `Parameters`.

Your only choice to overcome this is through [macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) which you would have to develop yourself in the form of a lambda function.

Comment: AWS::AccountId is great. Thank you. It will help with account id. Do you have a recommendation for the SSL certificate maybe?

Comment: @IgorShmukler `AWS::AccountId` will not work in `Parameters`. As I said, you have to create macro to do what you want.